# problem with installling texlive in windows 7

Tags: texlive

I am new to latex. I am trying to install Texlive in my windows PC. But I am facing the following problem.[image: Partial download of ..... is found, removing it]

The installation is in the same stage for more than one hour, but no change. I tried googling, no solutions found.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like a broken file download from the screen shot. This is likely a passing issue or one that is related to your particular set up, so beyond 'wait a bit' (say a day) or 'try a different mirror' (by choosing one explicitly using the 'advanced' installer), I'm not sure what we can say. Of course, the alternative would be to join a user group (I'm guessing DANTE for you) and get TeX Live on DVD.

Comment: If you're on windows, then you do have another option: miktex

Comment: Did you solve it? E.g. by aborting the installation and starting again?